# Cannot use belongsToMany to sync pivot data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a pivot table called `invite_riskarea_riskfield` which defined a relationship with the `invite` table:

[image]

What I need to do is sync multiple `invite_riskarea_riskfield` permissions (insert, edit, view). So I tried to set the following relationship in the `Invite` model:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        InviteRiskareaRiskfield::class,
        'invites',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

So I should be able to do `$invite->permissions()->sync($permissions);`

But the relationship returns this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invite_riskarea_riskfield.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `invite_riskarea_riskfield`.*, `invites`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `invite_riskarea_riskfield` inner join `invites` on `invite_riskarea_riskfield`.`id` = `invites`.`id` where `invites`.`id` = 17)

What I did wrong?

Comment: *"What I did wrong?"* - You specified `'id'` as both the Primary Key and Foreign Key (3rd and 4th argument) of `belongsToMany()`; one of those should probably be `'invite_id'`. I forget which one, but your `invite_riskarea_riskfield` does not have an `id` column.

Comment: And the `InviteRiskareaRiskfield` model seems to be the pivot model, so the definition itself is wrong

Comment: @IGP which relationship do you suggest to sync a list of `invite_riskarea_riskfield` with the `sync` method?

Comment: sync is only available for belongstomany relationships, so you'd need a relationship between invite <-> riskarea_riskfield (using invite_riskarea_riskfield as a pivot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your models are:

- `Invite` (`invites` table)
- `RiskAreaRiskField` (`riskarea_riskfield` table)
- `InviteRiskareaRiskfield` (`invite_riskarea_riskfield` table).

Your relationship should be the following. Feel free to change the method names to something that makes more sense to you.

```php
class Invite extends Model
{
    public function invite_riskarea_riskfield()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InviteRiskAreaRiskField::class, 'invite_id');
    }

    public function riskarea_riskfield()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(RiskAreaRiskField::class, 'invite_riskarea_riskfield', 'invite_id', 'riskarea_riskfield_id')
                    ->withPivot(['insert', 'edit', 'view'])
                    ->using(InviteRiskAreaRiskField::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class RiskAreaRiskField extends Model
{
    public function invite_riskarea_riskfield()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InviteRiskAreaRiskField::class, 'riskarea_riskfield_id');
    }

    public function invite()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invite::class, 'invite_riskarea_riskfield', 'riskarea_riskfield_id', 'invite_id')
                    ->withPivot(['insert', 'edit', 'view'])
                    ->using(InviteRiskAreaRiskField::class);
    }
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class InviteRiskareaRiskfield extends Pivot
{
    public function invite()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invite::class, 'invite_id');
    }

    public function riskarea_riskfield()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RiskAreaRiskField::class, 'riskarea_riskfield_id');
    }
}
```

```php
$invite = Invite::find(/* some id */);

// sync with riskarea_riskfield id 1, 2 and 3
$invite->riskarea_riskfield() // the belongsToMany relationship
    ->sync([
        1, // default values for insert, edit, view
        2 => ['insert' => 432, 'edit' => 13, 'view' => 542],
        3 => ['insert' => 654, 'edit' => 777, 'view' => 222]
    ]);


// sync with riskarea_riskfield id 4, 5 and 6 with the same permissions
$invite->riskarea_riskfield() // the belongsToMany relationship
    ->syncWithPivotValues(
        [4, 5, 6],
        ['insert' => 654, 'edit' => 777, 'view' => 222]
    );
```

Comment: if you have some free time could you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518270/how-to-access-to-pivot-data-using-multiple-condition